# Unable to produce special Signs like @ on German keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I cant create the @ character without googling it and i didnt find a reason why. On Windows the Command used to be "CTRL"+"ALT"+ "Q". The same problem is occurs for special characters like the "snakewave" "CTRL" + "ALT" + "+".
With ALT Gr it works though. Should i just rewire my brain and use "ALT GR" in the future or is there also an option to make "CTRL" + "ALT" Work in the same way as it does for windows?

Comment: which version of ubuntu, which keyboard layout selected may actually help someone provide an answer to your question. Maybe read [ask] then [edit] accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> With ALT Gr it works though. Should i just rewire my brain and use
> "ALT GR" in the future

Yes, I think that would be the best option. ;) <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the default key on Linux to access 3rd and 4th level symbols. As far as I know, using two modifier keys (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>) for that purpose is not possible.

It is possible, though, to pick some other single key. If you go to *Settings -> Keyboard* you find an "Alternate Characters Key" control from where you can change the key for accessing 3rd and 4th level symbols.